# How to skip line with matching pattern in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following lines in test.fa :

```
#test.fa
>1
AGAGGGAGCTG
CCTCAGGGCTG
CACTCAGGAAA
TTGGGGCGCTG
AGCATGGGGGG
CAGGAGGGGCC
```

I need to ignore the lines starting with ">" , and concatenate the following lines into one single string. The following script however not only skips lines with ">" , but also the next line before concatenating remaining.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import re
string = ""
with open("test.fa","rt") as f:
       for line in f:
           if re.match(">",line):
              line = f.next()
           else:
              line = line.rstrip("\n")
              string = string + line
print (string)
```

Could anyone help fix the script , or suggest better ways to do it? thanks !!

Comment: I will have a look , thanks jose

Comment: but, I recommend using Biopython [biopython parse fasta](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO#Sequence_Input)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line counter already increments every loop anyway, so you don't actually need to do anything in the `if` block.

```
   for line in f:
       if re.match(">",line):
          pass
       else:
          line = line.rstrip("\n")
          string = string + line
```

Or

```
   for line in f:
       if not re.match(">",line):
          line = line.rstrip("\n")
          string = string + line
```

---

Additional enhancements: you don't need regex to determine what character a string starts with, and accumulating lines in a list is generally recommended over concatenating a string.

```
lines = []
for line in f:
    if not line.startswith(">"):
        lines.append(line.rstrip("\n"))
string = "".join(lines)
```

Or, as a one liner:

```
string = "".join(line.rstrip("\n") for line in f if not line.startswith(">"))
```

Comment: thank you everyone !  all the solutions are similar, Thank you Kevin for the additional enhancements. helpful for any beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially calling `line.next()` twice since each time you loop, it is getting the next line.. I'd recommend going with this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import re
string = ""
with open("test.fa","rt") as f:
       for line in f:
           if not re.match(">",line):
              line = line.rstrip("\n")
              string = string + line
print (string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the

```
line = f.next()
```

that happens automatically in the iterator. Just do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import re

string = ""
with open("test.fa","rt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if not re.match(">",line):
            line = line.rstrip("\n")
            string = string + line
print (string)
```